# Can I Use neo4j cypher with other databases like orienddb?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Is It posible to use cypher to query databases from others vendors for example OriendDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Cypher is written for Neo4j only. You could use Gremlin as query language for both, check out the [Tinkerpop blueprints homepage](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database#Graph_database_features) also has a nice overview of graph databases and the query languages they support.

Answer (score 0):

[Pixy](https://github.com/lambdazen/pixy/wiki) is a declarative graph query language that works on any Blueprints-compatible graph database. The project documentation includes [an intro to Gremlin+Pixy for Cypher users.](https://github.com/lambdazen/pixy/wiki/Pixy-for-Cypher-users).